# Yarn is attempting to use the wrong version

Tags: reactjs, node.js, yarn-berry, corepack

I have Node.js v20 with corepack enabled on my PC. When I run `yarn -v` it shows **v4.1.0** (latest). But when I run `yarn dlx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` in an empty directory it comes back with this error:

```
Internal Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\node\corepack\yarn\4.0.1'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\node\corepack\yarn\4.0.1'
```

This error also appears if I just run `yarn dlx blah`.

Looking under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\node\corepack\yarn` there is no 4.0.1 directory (but there are several others, including 4.1.0).

Why is it trying to access v4.0.1 and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally ran across a corepack [bug report](https://github.com/nodejs/corepack/issues/334) that pretty much captures this issue. Unfortunately nobody is currently working it.

Another finding was that running `yarn dlx create-react-app .\my-app --template typescript` requires Yarn v4.0.1 whereas running `yarn create react-app .\my-app --template typescript` used v4.1.0 all the way through. The latter is also the [recommended](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) way to initialize a new React app.